# CSS won't load its properties

Tags: html, css, macos

I'm a new user to Stack Overflow and web development.

I've been searching for reasons as to why this script does not function properly but came to no conclusion. The CSS won't change the color, position of the text nor will the font family. However, the html is perfectly fine.

I don't know reasons as to why the CSS won't work but I'm using a Mac OS X and the Atom text editor.

Can anyone guide me into solving this issue? The code is below:

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1.title {
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: 300;
}

figure {
  margin: auto;
}

.title {
  padding: 100px 0;
  max-width: 640px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Edit as people asked for the html. Thanks for asking! Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheets/Homepage Styling.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Adrian" />
    <meta name="description" content="A portfolio of past works." />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Adrian's Portfolio</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Clothing Store</h1>
      <hr />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Nullam imperdiet urna ut purus ornare consequat.
        Donec sed mauris non urna bibendum rhoncus. Sed dignissim leo id pulvinar
        laoreet. Nam at finibus urna. Mauris fermentum quam nec tempor consequat.
        Aenean congue eros ipsum, ac fermentum lorem consectetur sit amet.
        Quisque porttitor ex eros, in feugiat nunc pretium sit amet.
        Vivamus dapibus nulla id eros malesuada varius.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show the html page where u have added this css

Comment: How do you include the CSS in your HTML? Inline or with a `<link>` tag?

Comment: and make sure the path to it is correct

Comment: another thing; if you're using some type of framework, make sure that those rules aren't being ignored/overriden. If so, use `!important`.

Comment: Seems fine at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2kC7HQ7XqVhIpOHBr7n?p=preview)

Comment: HTML added. I use the link tag to access the CSS. No frameworks are being used either. Does the href not accept spacing in its value for a file name?

Comment: again; check your file path and its name (folder/file). It could be that the folder/filename are case-sensitive. Look at your html source. Plus, if this is related to your text editor, check to see what the encoding is. I don't use Mac so I can't test this. Everything worked fine for me also (edit: see another of my comment below), both on Windows / Linux.

Comment: now, is this for everything or just for h1? if that's the case, then the inheritance is wrong.

Comment: `h1` doesn't has class of `.title`, it is class of parent div. So it has to be `.title h1 { .. .}` . And `text-align` property add to paragraph `title p { text-align:center }

Comment: ^ I thought of that also. However, OP seems to say that none are being applied. This sounds more like a mixed bag and a path/filenaming convention issue to me.

Comment: *"Does the href not accept spacing in its value for a file name?"* - That will depend on your OS; and I don't see an issue with that. However, the space may be getting converted to a `%20`, so rename the file with either no space, or an underscore. As I said, I tested this on both Windows and Linux with no issues with the space

Comment: `href="assets/stylesheets/Homepage Styling.css"` - if you're trying to run your initial page that isn't just **outside** of `assets` such as `"your_folder/file.htm/assets....` as a sort of diagram here, then that too is failing. I feel the question is unclear, but you have answers below, ask them. I did what I could to help you here, @AdrianWarholm you can ping me back if you want, I've left the question.

Comment: After doing a bit work, "Does the href not accept spacing in its value for a file name?" - That will depend on your OS; and I don't see an issue with that. However, the space may be getting converted to a %20, so rename the file with either no space, or an underscore. As I said, I tested this on both Windows and Linux with no issues with the space –" from Fred-ii- comment worked.

Thank you for helping. It took a while as I actually thought it was the code but the code was fine.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS code will not change the color or weight of the **H1** because you are applying color to **H1** with "*title*" class. But in the **H1** tag there is no "*title*" class. Other properties are working fine I assume.

Replace the following with the correct ones.

```
h1.title{
  color: red;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Solution one:

```
h1{
  color: red;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Solution two:

```
.title h1{
  color: red;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: OP: *"The CSS won't change the color, position of the the text **nor will the font family**"*. Explain that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have updated my answer with mentioning about the font-weight beside the color, because this was declared in the css for the H1

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the name of the stylesheet that you're trying to link. Try again with an underscore

Comment: spaces are allowed and we don't know their actual filename for it